# Does sha256 is ok for that? If not does EC?

Tags: hash, public-key, signature, hash-signature

I think from what I studied that I had the correct reasoning, but I would like a double check. Here is the thing:

Given two matrix: **A** and **B**

I calculate the hashFunction(A, B) = **C**

Now I calcultate the eigenvalues of **B**: **µ** and the associate vector **x**

Now is the following equation correct:

**C * x = hashFunction(A, µ) * x = hashFunction(A, µ*x)**

Is it true given any hashfunction?
Specifically given sha256, or Elliptic Curve Function, or any other?

**EDIT:**

My aim is, given a public information, to show that I am the owner of the information and gives other information, and avoids that if someone intercepts the password I give before it comes to the audience, he cannot uses it to gives different information.

So for the problem I gave, data are:

B is public

TO authentify me, I give hash(A, µ) and x

**2nd EDIT**

The answer to my question seems to rely in Signature as described in [this paper](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography/cryptography_digital_signatures.htm). Has anyone an example of signature and verification algorithms ?

3rd EDIT:

So I implemented something, could it be use

```
encoded_Pwd=str(Input_STR).encode("utf-8")
key=hashlib.md5(encoded_Pwd).hexdigest()
PRIVATE_KEY = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(key.encode("utf-8"))
```

Then:

```
PUBLIC_KEY=sha256(PRIVATE_KEY).hexdigest()
```

Comment: It is $$\text{By no means}$$ What is your aim?

Comment: @kelalaka do you mean the equation is false? even two first members?

Comment: sha256 is nonlinear - so, what do you mean by an 'eigenvector'?  And, why do you expect sha256 to exhibit them?

Comment: the eigenvector is associated with the eigenvalue µ
that is in fact my question: would it be possible with another crypto algorithm that still avoids to find back A and B given C ?

Comment: What you ask is not clear! Hash functions are one-way functions. One cannot find A and B from C if A and B are large-sized data. Why do you expect a matrix out of SHA-246?

Comment: well actually i am searching for the hashfunction that has also  the property in my question
well the output of sha256 of a matrix is  a vector? Or a number?

Comment: Of cource you can consider the 256-bit output of SHA-256 as 8x8 bit matrix, however, by no mean you will get such equalities.

Comment: ok and there is no means for any hash function to get the result: 
C*x = hashFunction(A, µ*x)

Comment: What is your aim, this is more important. In multi-party computations, there are tons of protocols to achieve various aims...

Comment: My aim is, given a public information, to show that I am the owner of the information and gives other information, and avoids that if someone intercepts the password I give before it comes to the audience, he cannot uses it to gives different informatio

Comment: Still not clear, Zero-knowledge and hash commitments..

Comment: @kelalaka look at the second edit

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, but all you need is to generate a Public and Private Keys, then share Public key and Sign your document with your Private key.
This way, everybody knowing your Public key will be able to verify, that document is signed by you (i.e. the one who knows Private Key).

Comment: Thank you this is what I searched for but would you have practical examples of that? Like algotrithm or code to sign the document? to verify the signature?

Comment: Hi I edited the question with a little code, could you please tell me if it is in accordance with the SIgnature thing?

Comment: @totalMongot See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature. For an example of software that implements digital signatures, check out GnuPG.